# When to use useImmer vs useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

When should you useState vs useImmer?

With the major overhaul of the react documentation, there has been more recommendations in the react documentation to utilize useImmer instead of useState for easier readibility it seems.

As someone that is still new to frontend coding, I am still somewhat confused as to when to useImmer over useState? I have read that it is best used with nested objects or arrays, should this be when useImmer is mainly used over useState, as with useImmer from what I have read, I can also safely mutate arrays and objects? Although not recommended to mutate arrays and objects with useState.

When to useState vs useImmer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need to use `useImmer`. It is not part of `react`, but another package that makes dealing with more complex state a bit easier.

If you already have the `use-immer` package installed, then you'd use `useImmer` when your state is an object or array, while using `useState` for simpler datatypes, such as `string`, `number`, and `boolean`.

For example:

```js
const initialUser = {
  name: 'Luke Skywalker',
  friends: ['Han Solo', 'Chewy', 'Leia'],
};

const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [immerUser, updateImmerUser] = useImmer(initialUser);
const [stateUser, setStateUser] = useState(initialUser);

function inc() {
  setCount(count + 1);
}

function addImmerFriend(newFriendName) {
  updateImmerUser(draft => {
    draft.friends.push(newFriendName)
  })
}

function addStateFriend(newFriendName) {
  setStateUser({
    ...stateUser,
    friends: [
     ...stateUser.friends,
     newFriendName,
    ],
  })
}
```